# How to add reference of compiled assembly to Roslyn scripting API?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, roslyn

I was able to compile C# code using Roslyn and generate an Assembly by following certain online resources. I am now wondering if it is possible to include that assembly in Roslyn's Scripting api. 
Something like:

```
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(reference);
var script = CSharpScript.Create("var x = new MyClass();", options);
var state = script.RunAsync().Result;
```

I've tried of creating a reference via

```
var reference = MetadataReference.CreateFromImage(ms.ToArray());
```

However, I kept getting an exception, something like `This stream does not support seek operations.`

Thank you.